# How to change the images dynamically inside for loop in angular6?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

My html code:

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-12">
           <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontal of categories">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let horizontalval of horizontal.items;let i=index">
          <button [ngClass]="{'selected-color' : i==selectedIndex}" type="submit" class="btn1" [id]="horizontal.items[i].title" (click)="changeTrans(horizontal.items[i].title);changeColor(i)"> 
            <img [src]= horizontal.items[i].icon alt="image not found" class="icon"/>
            {{ horizontal.items[i].title }}
          </button>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container></div>
      </div>
```

So my component.ts file,

```
 changeColor(i){
  console.log(i);
this.selectedIndex = i;
}
```

my css:

```
.selected-color{
 background-color: orange;
 color:white;
// background-image: url('./../../../../../assets/Trans_1.png');
}
```

So here I am able to change the color of the selected button, but I also need to change different images for different values. Here, how can I change my image dynamically for every button id?

Basically what I want to know is, how to change the image dynamically for every button which is going to be displayed via for. Can anybody suggest me something to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let horizontalval of horizontal.items;let i=index">
```

by

```
<img [attr.src]= "horizontalval.icon" alt="image not found" class="icon"/>
```

**`Edit`**

Note : object `horizontalval` should have attribute `icon` which will have `path` of `image`.

If you want to change the path for entire image then you can use `selectedIndex`.

```
<img [src]= "horizontal.items[selectedIndex].icon" class="icon"/>
```

#### Edit

```
    <button [ngClass]="{'selected-color' : horizontal.items[i].selected}" 
      type="submit" class="btn1" [id]="horizontal.items[i].title"
 (click)="changeTrans(horizontal.items[i].title);
         changeColor(horizontal.items[i])">        
       <img [src]= horizontal.items[i].icon alt="image not found" class="icon"/>
                {{ horizontal.items[i].title }}
      </button>
```

#### ts

```
changeColor(item){
  this.item.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see the images of the button onload. What I want is onclick of the button I need to replace the image with another image for every buttons. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Updated the answer with `<img [src]= horizontal.items.items[selectedIndex].icon class="icon"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much. Image is changing, but for every button Im getting the same images. (ex. If I click the first button, the image of the button needs to be changed to aaa, if i click the 2nd button the image of the button needs to be changed to bbb)

Comment: I updated the answer in edit section. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: It is still not working for me. could you please give me any other solution if its there? please..